# How do I disable the CAPS LOCK function WITHOUT disabling the key or remapping it?

Tags: windows, window, capslock

I was looking for a way to disable the CAPS LOCK functionality in windows. Unfortunately all solutions are about remapping it to NOTHING or other keys. I am a gamer and want to use the CAPS LOCK key for in-game function but I don't want Windows to CAPITALIZE everything after I use caps lock (for example using CAPS lock for changing target in an space FPS which uses WASD to fly).

Example:

CAPS LOCK is mapped to "Change Target" in my gam

I press CAPS Lock, Windows from now on will capitalize all my typed text

I shoot my target but I need assistance, so I enter the chat now I want to type but all the letters are capitalized

So to avoid capitalized text I again press CAPS LOCK but then my target is changed, however now I cn type with normal text.

So is there any trick to disable capitalizing functionality in Windows without having to remap the CAPS LOCK key to something else?

In short: I want it to be detected by games etc without enabling capitalized text.

Comment: Why not remap Caps Lock to some other key that you don't use - F12 maybe, or backslash - then tell the game to use that key for "Change Target"?

Comment: @HarryJohnston [NumLocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/NumLocker.shtml) works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one way to achieve the result you want, but it's not ideal. You could remap actual keys so capslock state does not affect them. In other words, to ignore <kbd>capslock</kbd> modifier. This works (in fact I'm writing this with <kbd>capslock ON</kbd> and modified keyboard - but there is a glitch - if effectively also disables producing capital letters with <kbd>shift</kbd>. While there is possibility to make a separate mapping for that, it's not recognized by any programs I tried (with the exception of layout mapper tester itself). So whenever I need to put a capital, I have to switch to normal keyboard layout (via <kbd>ctl+alt+digit</kbd> shortcut) - not super convenient, but it does not change `caps` state!

I've used [Microsoft keyboard layout Creator 1.4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) to build the layout.

Some background information on how the keyboard evens are actually processed (to add to your discussion with soandos: *(simplified)*:
when a key is pressed it produces a scancode. This scancode is processed by windows (keyboard driver) and translated into `virtual key`. This `virtual key` (value) is then sent to application. For <kbd>capslock</kbd> `VC_CAPITAL` is being sent (and interpreted by your game). Virtual code is not character key yet. After receiving VK_CODE (and maybe reacting somehow to it) application will ask OS for actual character code. Now what code is returned to application depends on several factors OS keeps track of - capslock status being one of them. That's why capslock works across apps - as it's being tracked by OS and not (only) an app. [More here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: that's one possible solution, better than last answer, however NumLocker (freeware) seemed to work perfectly for me.

Comment: @GamErix Ah good - nice little utility, worth to know. It's pluggable architecture so a lot is possible with dedicated 'plugins'.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this exact issue, so I made my own keyboard layout using [KbdEdit](http://kbdedit.com) where the letter keys ignore caps lock (without changing the behavior of shift). The layout is publicly available [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_A8qcFNS8qnINQlBwsxB4IKy78nmSHwN); simply run the installer and switch to the new layout in your language bar.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible. If a game detects a key, it can make it do whatever it wants (in this case enter capitalized text). There is no way to change that without changing the code for the game.

**Expanding:**

Hitting the caps lock key is in most cases a hardware thing (a light may go on etc). That behavior is then mapped by whatever application you are using at the time. If your game decided to ignore that, it could. If it wanted to make every letter you typed after that an 'A' it could. In this case, it decided to follow convention and make letters capitalized if the caps lock key is on.

Once you leave the game, the caps lock key will still be on because its a hardware thing. Windows sees that, and also decides to follow convention and make your letters capitalized.

Comment: please explain why the CAPS LOCK command cannot be intercepted? I want the key be able to be detectable but at the same time not enabling "CAPS LOCK" in windows. This has to be possible.

Comment: maybe this is more clear: "I'm wondering if there is a way to actually just disable the function of the key (as a caps toggle) without actually remapping the key itself?"

Comment: nono it's not the game but WINDOWS capitalizes the text.

Comment: basicly it goes this way: CAPS LOCK -> hardware switch -> I type 'a' -> Windows Sends 'A' to the Game.

Comment: so I want to send 'a' directly to the game.

Comment: No. Its caps lock->hardware switch->you type 'a'->windows sends 'a' and caps lock is pressed -> game prints 'A"

Comment: in the games source code there is nothing that detects if caps lock is on to capitalize the text. So I think windows is doing it. Can you please send a link on how you know that? :$ (reference)

Comment: It is going a text box from a library? That is where the code would be (and you may or may not have access to that code)

Comment: tried the registry hack and some games crash when the caps lock is pressed on mapping and some games return 'NONE' key nd some just wait for other input buttons..

Comment: ah also I tried 'sending' caps lock to a game via program which can send text messages by pressing a key on the keyboard, it also workd with keys like enter, control and caps lock. So I mapped Caps Lock in the program to return and when I used return the program sent the key to the game and it changed my target but the text typing wasn't capitalized after that.

Comment: ok just mapped it to F13

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar capability and I was surprised that there was no native support in Windows to manage this. While other answers suggest the use of MSKLC or NumLocker that could functionally achieve the end goal, neither tool was what I was looking for (a simple zero-configuration open-source utility that focused on Caps Lock key).

To deal with this, I made my own utility which monitors the Caps Lock key state and attempts to force it in a toggled off state:

> Caps Block
> https://github.com/jdknight/capsblock

I dedicate my Caps Lock key to voice applications (like Discord/TeamSpeak), and since running this tool I no longer have situations where my Caps Lock modifier is accidentally left on from any recent communication.

Answer (score -1):

Some keyboards (such as those from WASD Keyboards) have hardware DIP switches that allow you to modify the function of certain keys, including <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd>. In the case of the WASD V2 keyboards, turning on Switch 3 will let CAPS LOCK works like the left control key.

[image: V2/V2B User's Guide]

Answer (score -1):

To quickly and simply solve your problem of inadvertently pressing the CapsLock key, download and install 'CapsUnlock' - a free app. Then to enable CapsLock you have to hold down the Shift key and press the CapsLock key; pressing the CapsLock key only doesn't turn it on. To turn off CapsLock, just press the CapsLock key. Lots easier than changing the Registry.