# Change Caps Lock to still register as caps lock but do Nothing

Tags: windows, keyboard, capslock

Currently my caps lock key functions exactly like it should, is it possible for me to disable the function that converts inputs to capital without disabling detection of the actual key and without re-mapping to something else. I am using a program to detect key presses and want the triggering key to be the caps lock key, but without caps lock auto-capitalizing everything. For reference, I am using Logitech Gaming Software for key press detection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable the CAPS LOCK function WITHOUT disabling the key or remapping it?](https://superuser.com/questions/490737/how-do-i-disable-the-caps-lock-function-without-disabling-the-key-or-remapping-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AutoHotKey ( https://autohotkey.com/ ) you can remap the CapsLock button into a hotkey, and it will prevent the default purpose of the key.

AutoHotKey also comes with all the documentation you need to use it, including a 'quick start' tutorial for people who don't want to get into majorly complex hotkeys.

Comment: I can see how that would be useful to remap the key, but how would I be able to use it to change the function of the key?

Comment: AutoHotKey allows you not only to remap keys, but make entire scripts that run from a keypress. In essence, it can make a key do most things.

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough, I have another program that I want to use to detect key presses, and I want to use caps lock as the hotkey to be detected, but for that to work I would need to stop it from changing inputs to capital letters without effecting the ability for the key press to be detected, let me update the OP.

Comment: Fair enough, then might I suggest using AutoHotKey to prevent the auto-capitalization and see if your capture software still sees the keypress? Just have the AutoHotKey script do nothing on the CapsLock:: capture

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator, load the default US keyboard layout, and disable the "CAPS=Shift" option for all of the keys which have it enabled. Then you can install it and load the layout as an input language (language bar options). To expedite the process, here's the built install I just made (you'll still need to set your input to use this keyboard):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbag84s7vjykv1x/usnocaps.zip?dl=1
Here's Microsoft's Keyboard Layout Creator:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx

Comment: Will this disable the ability to capitalize letters with shift?

Comment: No, it only disables capitalization with caps-lock, and you can enable/disable caps lock any time by switching keyboard layouts via a hotkey (which you can set in the language bar options, I believe Ctrl+Shift is the default). Sorry for the slow reply, I'm still getting used to the site and wasn't aware you had commented.